# Using addClass to show an interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I'm attempting to show an interval within a bar. Initially I was using the jQuery plugin for range, but it did not work like I wanted.

I have several different bulleted pointed within my bar. Whenever someone clicks within or near the point (in the class `sliderInterval`) I want the class `rangeSection` to be added to that area, basically showing that certain interval active. However, the `rangeSection` doesn't even show up, nor I am certain I am doing this correctly.

In addition, since I am doing this with intervals. I want to be able to give those intervals values, so that when one is selected I can display that value.

This is what I am trying to get it to look like:

[image]

I added a snippet to show what I have done so far. Any advise?

```js
$(function interval() {
  $(".slideInterval").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass(".rangeSection");
  });
});
```

```css
#sliderBar {
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 25px 10%;
  background: blue;
}
.rangeSection {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  color: purple;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.intervalCircle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
.sliderInterval {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 8%;
}
.sliderInterval:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.intervalCircle:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sliderBar">
<div class="rangeSection"></div>
  <div class="sliderInterval" onclick="interval()"><span class="intervalCircle" ></span></div>
  <div class="sliderInterval" onclick="interval()"><span class="intervalCircle" ></span></div>
  <div class="sliderInterval" onclick="interval()"><span class="intervalCircle"></span></div>
  <div class="sliderInterval" onclick="interval()"><span class="intervalCircle"></span></div>
  <div class="sliderInterval" onclick="interval()"><span class="intervalCircle"></span></div>
  <div class="sliderInterval" onclick="interval()"><span class="intervalCircle"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No `.active` `class` declaration appears at `css` ?

Comment: @guest271314 Right... I just noticed that. I changed my JS. I am updating the fiddle.

Comment: Note also that `interval` is not defined globally

Comment: I thought at `interval()` I was just setting the name of the function?

Comment: What is expected result of `onclick="interval()"` ?

Comment: I thought that was how I initiated the `click` function.

Comment: What is purpose of `$(".slideInterval").click(function() ` ? Also `.` not necessary at `className` parameter provided to `.addClass()`

Comment: As you can tell I am new to this. I was looking off of an example and followed that. I thought I had to add the name of the class where I was clicking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one.

You can use the .ready(); function of the jQuery library and set the .click() listener on all the .sliderInterval elements. I added the active class as well.

try it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/8cxLLts1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sliderInterval").click(function() {
       $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

EDIT: actually, if you use toggleClass() instead of addClass(), you'll be able to turn on and off a specific section

Comment: Is there anyway I can get this to fadeIn and then slide to the other intervals when they are chosen? I tried `toggleClass`, but that isn't sufficient.

Comment: I did an update of the fiddle. Try to have a look, now it should work.

Comment: Could you send an updated Fiddle? The link still goes to the old one.

Comment: here you are... https://jsfiddle.net/8cxLLts1/3/
the left position is -70 beacuse includes 10+10 px of padding and half of the width.

Answer (score 0):

Using onclick in your html attribute and then binding a click event also in js could be considered redundant and unnecessary. Try removing the onclick attribute from your html and then adjust your js like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
})
.on('click', '.sliderInterval', function(){
    $(this).addClass(".rangeSection");
});
```

Bind it to the document itself and this will help with your event delegation naturally. Also, take care to double check your class names - your js is missing the 'r' in '.sliderInterval'.